# Modified jQuery innerfade sluggish

Tags: jquery

HI.   I am using the jQuery innerfade plugin to scroll through some images on my site.  Innerfade is sluggish to move on Firefox 3.6.3, and IE 8.  IE 8 is much worse than Firefox, and Chrome runs smoothly.

Can you analyze my code to see what the problem is?  I've used the modified innerfade from here: http://www.stylephp.com/2009/01/17/customizing-jquery-innerfade-plug-in-adding-controls-navigation-and-caption/

My sites are here:

Without bg image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/145908/doozie2/index.html

With bg image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/145908/doozie2/index2.html

Removing my background image fixes the situation; it's not that big of a  file.  I don't understand why that is an issue.  I am using a technique to resize the image to fit the browser window, as you can see in the CSS.

Thanks so much.

<del>P.S.  Sorry, I'm a new user so I can't post more than one link.  Please copy and paste the address between <>.</del>

Comment: edited for you... Welcome to stackoverflow.com... ;)

Comment: Safari/Mac OSX shows it pretty good...

Comment: Thanks!  This is a useful site and there's usually an answer to my question so I've never felt the need to ask a question before.